# Do you die instantaneously if your life total hits 0?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Way back when, the first combo I built a deck around was

[Force of Nature](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233304)
with a
[Spirit Link](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=129744)
on it. If, at the beginning of my upkeep, I have less than 8 life and I don't pay the upkeep, will I lose the game before the life gain kicks in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 104.3b If a player’s life total is 0 or less, he or she loses the game the next time a player would    receive priority. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.)

When the Force of Nature damages you, Spirit Link's trigger goes on the stack. If, between sustaining the damage and getting 8 life back from Link, your life total hits 0, you'll die.

This is confirmed by [the Oracle text for Spirit Link](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=129744):

> You only gain the life when the triggered ability resolves. If you are
>   reduced to zero life before the ability resolves, you will lose before
>   gaining the life.

Luckily, you can avoid this problem by replacing Spirit Link with [Lifelink](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220182).

Comment: Note that in earlier versions of the rules, life totals weren't checked until the end of a phase or combat, so you had plenty of time for the trigger to resolve and bring you above 0 life. I'm not sure when this changed to the modern ruling, but it was well after Force of Nature and Spirit Link were printed.

Comment: @StuartCook Actually, the change was made for Sixth Edition, so Spirit Link was reprinted five times after this change, even though it was made significantly weaker. The *Lifelink* keyword was introduced in **Future Sight** on two [spells from the future](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=+[Lifelink]&set=[%22Future%20Sight%22]) when evidently new magic spell technology "fixed" Spirit Link. :) Thus, Spirit Link was replaced by Lifelink in the next M10 base set.

Comment: @ghoppe The funny thing is that Future Sight lifelink it didn't even "fix" Spirit Link right away! The first iteration of lifelink was also a triggered ability (see the reminder text on Daybreak Coronet), and all the old lifelink-like spells were changed to use it in Oracle. Then, even later, the rules team decided to make it a damage-changing static ability, and all the old cards had their Oracle text reverted -- except Loxodon Warhammer, which had already been reprinted with "lifelink" in the text box (oops!).

Comment: Perfect example of how some cards make old cards completely obsolete. :D

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer - I wouldn't call it obsolete.  Multiple Spirit Links stack whereas multiple Lifelinks do not.

Comment: and you can't lifelink your opponents creature to gain back the damage it does